# How to tell java.lang.String.split to skip the delimiter?

Tags: java

as input my program gets a String containing IP Addresses are separated by a line delimiter, i.e. one IP Address per line. To validate each of the addresses I do:

```
String[] temp;
temp = address.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

and then I loop though the array of Strings.

I was wondering why all but the last IP Address were always invalid. I've found out, that they look like 10.1.1.1^M

Is there a way to tell the java.lang.String.split to drop the delimiter before putting the token into the array? Or what other options do I have here? Sorry, I'm not a Java Ninja, so I thought I'll ask you guys before I start googling for hours.

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: By default the `.split()` method removes the delimiter. Posting an example of what you are using and what you are getting will help.

Comment: The problem probably isn't split() but the way you're using the strings...

Comment: can you elaborate ob that Shark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the delimiter in your file is `"\r\n"`, but the value of `System.getProperty("line.separator")` is `"\n"`. This means that the `"\r"` is not treated as part of the delimiter.

Comment: So what do you suggest? address.split(System.getProperty('\n\r'));?

Comment: I would use `\\s+` to break on any number of white spaces.

Comment: @Thomas If you use `address.split("\r\n")` and then suddenly you want to process a file which was created on a Unix machine, then the split will fail.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just use `address.split("\\s+")` since *valid* IP addresses can never contain spaces in them?

**Predefined character classes**

```
.     Any character (may or may not match line terminators) 
\d    A digit: [0-9] 
\D    A non-digit: [^0-9] 
\s    A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r] 
\S    A non-whitespace character: [^\s] 
\w    A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9] 
\W    A non-word character: [^\w]
```

Comment: I guess, it's because whitespace is not my delimiter. There is 1 IP Address per line in that String. Or what do you mean?

Comment: `Whitespace = space, \n, \t, \r`

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using a different carriage return from that of the platform. (e.g. editing on MS-DOS/Windows and running on Linux)

I would use `\\s+` to break on any number of white spaces. This will also trim leading or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your line.separator is not valid. It depends on the system you are using:

```
\n = CR (Carriage Return) // Used as a new line character in Unix
\r = LF (Line Feed) // Used as a new line character in Mac OS
\n\r = CR + LF // Used as a new line character in Windows
```

Comment: If my line separator would not be valid, then I guess that the split function wouldn't be able to fill make the array. Still this part is works just fine.